# How can I get the calling query from within a Spark UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Few years ago, writing a Hive UDF in a Hadoop environment, I could get the calling query like so:

```
public class MyHiveUDF extends GenericUDF { 

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws CryptoException { ...stuff...}

    @Override
    public void configure(MapredContext context) {
        super.configure(context);
        Configuration conf = context.getJobConf();
        String myQuery = conf.get("hive.query.string","")
    }
```

Now trying to do something similar in Spark/Scala (Databricks job/notebook), I want my UDF get hold of the calling query - is that possible? if so, how?
And as a more general question - can I get any of the Spark configuration inside a UDF code?

My platform is using Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12, Databricks version 11.x

It should look something like this:

```
def myCustomUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf ( (colValue : String) => {
  val myQuery = ...get query string here?...
  stuffWithInput(colVal)
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Try with - `spark.hadoop.hive.query.string`

Comment: @MohanaBC how is that available to me inside a UDF? - this is called in the executors, not in the driver